# Remove file after fpassthru, is there a callback?

Tags: php

This could works perfectly in passing a zipped file back to the client. But the little snippet at the end unlinking the file doesn't seem to be working?

I am assuming that the fpassthru locks the file, so the unlink cannot do anything..

Is there a callback option available.. something to remove the file after the client has received it?

```
// we deliver a zip file
header("Content-Type: archive/zip");
// filename for the browser to save the zip file
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$guideName".".zip");
$filesize = filesize($zip_file);
header("Content-Length: $filesize");

// deliver the zip file
$fp = fopen($zip_file,'r');
echo fpassthru($fp);

// clean up the tmp zip file
unlink($zip_file);
exit();
```

Comment: Doing this will cause you headaches when the file was successfully transferred, or otherwise went wrong. A better approach would be to create a timed link, and unlink the file after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the file is opened, it's locked and cannot be deleted.

```
fclose($fp);
unlink($zip_file);
```

Also make sure the file is writable by the www-user / fpm script owner (=> chmod).

To debug this, I suggest a combination of error reporting, output buffers and mail:

```
ob_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
fclose($fp);
unlink($zip_file);
$debug = ob_get_contents();
mail('you@server', 'error in zip upload', var_export($debug, true));
```

Another sidenote is the concatenation here:

```
("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$guideName".".zip")
```

Properly:

```
("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $guideName . ".zip")
```

You could also use `file_get_contents()` which is basically the same as fopen, fpassthru, fclose in once:

```
header("Content-Length: $filesize");
// deliver the zip file
echo file_get_contents($zip_file);
// clean up the tmp zip file
unlink($zip_file);
```

Comment: will this only close the file after the client has completed the data transaction?

Comment: This will close and unlink the file after it has been sent to the client.

Comment: Since you never use ignore_user_abort your unlink is not guaranteed to run, even with ignore_user_abort if script is killed unlink may not be executed so eventually you will start getting stale files in that folder.

Comment: @hidden_4003 Good comment! On Debian there is a php garbage collection cron, one could simply extend it to delete files which are older than 1 day or something. Other way would be to create a ticket in a database which stores information. I would also try to implement the possibility to pause a download and go on at a later time, this implies a disconnect but the file not to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You are ceating a file handle with the call to fopen, which is what will be locking the file. You need to ensure that you call fclose before unlink. E.g.

```
$fp = fopen($zip_file,'r');
echo fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);
unlink($zip_file);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is an error in your code which will most likely corrupt the file you are sending:

> Return values
>
> If an error occurs, fpassthru() returns FALSE. Otherwise, fpassthru()
>   returns the number of characters read from handle and passed through
>   to the output.

Therefore your code should look like:

```
// deliver the zip file
$fp = fopen($zip_file,'r');
fpassthru($fp);
```

Notice there is no echo before fpassthru.

A MUCH more reliable solution would be to run a separate script to clean the folder where these files are stored every x minutes/hours/days.

If the file is open and you delete it, it is still open and can be read from, but no longer accessible by file name. When script terminates and file handle is closed the space taken by the file will be freed.

The other possible way is using session shutdown handler.